# Value of optional type must be unwrapped to refer to member, BUT its for an implicitly unwrapped optional property

Tags: swift, option-type

Why am I getting this?  Its an implicitly unwrapped optional property.  I don't think I should be getting this error.  I tried cleaning my build folder and deleting derived data, and closing Xcode. Nothing worked.

```
var questionsWrap: QuestionsWrapper
    
func userMadeSelection(
    _ responseId: Int,
    _ myTheir: Question.Response.Selections.MyTheir,
    _ choice: Question.Response.Selections.MyTheir.Choice
) {
    guard let id = question.id else { return }
    questionsWrap.saveSelection(
        questionId: id,
        responseID: responseId,
        myTheir: myTheir,
       choice: choice
    ) { success in
        if !success {
           AlertViewController<Any>.alertFailure(
               message:  "We made a mistake and we weren't able to save your selection."
            )
        }
    }
    singleQuestionDataSource.observableQuestion.value = question
    print(#line, "userMadeSelectionImportance: \(responseId) \(myTheir) \(choice)")
    if choice.changedBetweenPolarAndNeutral(
        with: questionsWrap.question.theirInteractionStyle
        ) {
        let presenter = Question.Importance.Presenter(question)
        update(presenter?.importance)
        questionCell?.importancePresenter = presenter
    }
}
```

Method definition

```
func saveSelection(
    questionId: Int,
    responseID: Int,
    myTheir: Question.Response.Selections.MyTheir,
    choice: Question.Response.Selections.MyTheir.Choice,
    context: Context,
    successAction: SuccessAction? = nil
) {
        
        guard let questionIndex = questions.index(of: questionId),
            let responseIndex = questions[questionIndex].responses.index(of: responseID) else {
                successAction?(false)
                return
        }
        
        questions[questionIndex].responses[responseIndex].set(myTheir, choice, for: context)
        let response = questions[questionIndex].responses[responseIndex]
        URL.make(
           my: response.choice(for: .my, UserDefaults.questionContext),
           their: response.choice(for: .their, UserDefaults.questionContext),
           forResponseID: responseID,
           forQuestionID: questionId,
           forContext: UserDefaults.questionContext
           ).get { jsonDict in
            successAction?(jsonDict.success)
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, I don't know what code to provide to recreate this issue atomically.

I am stepping outside of the norm and posting a screen shot to prove that the error is showing.

[image]

Comment: Please post *code,*  not screenshots. Ideally a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you @MartinR . I did so.  I had no idea I'd get 5 downvotes in a few hours for my forgetting.  You'd think the point would be conveyed by 1 or 2.  Anyway, thanks for informing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, I changed the method signature for `saveSelection` to require another parameter, but I forgot to add a default value or add the argument in the call.  I don't know why the compiler wasn't telling me that instead...

Comment: I still can't reproduce the error message you're getting. Can you provide sufficient code to allow me to reproduce? If you can, I can report a bug to the Swift people (because, as you rightly imply, the error message is misleading).

Comment: Without including my whole project I have yet to reproduce it.  I frankly don’t know where to begin.

Comment: Understood. Probably not worth spending your time on! Anyway, your intuition that the implicitly unwrapped Optional should not generate the "you need to unwrap this" error is certainly right. This situation should have generated some other error.

Answer (score 2):

The usual reason for seeing this error message with an implicitly unwrapped Optional is that implicit unwrapping does not promulgate itself thru assignment. For example, this is legal:

```
    var s : String!
    print(s.count)
```

But this is not:

```
    let s2 = s
    print(s2.count) // value must be unwrapped
```

Comment: Whoa, I didn't know about that! That's worthwhile on its own.  Unfortunately, I'm not chaining the property assignment anywhere.